# Nested Routes not working - v2.3.0

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here are my routes:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={LoginPage} />
    <Route path="login" component={LoginPage} />
    <Route path="logout" component={Logout} />
    <Route path="forgot-password" component={ForgotPasswordPage} />
    <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={this._requireAuth} />
    <Route path="users" component={UsersList} onEnter={this._requireAuth}>
      <Route path="add" component={UserAdd} onEnter={this._requireAuth} />
      <Route path="status" component={UserStatus} onEnter={this._requireAuth} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

If I try to access **/users** route like `<Link to="/users">Users</Link>`, ti works just fine. But, when I try to access **/users/add** or **/users/status** like `<Link to="/users/add">Add User</Link>` or `<Link to="/users/status">User Status</Link>`, nothing happens. There is no error in the console, just the page is blank.

Comment: what is the error in the console?

Comment: @Mohit Please check answer.

Answer (score 0):

I created an empty component which redirects to **/users**. Then created an index route inside that route, which renders a list component inside **/users**. Also, created another route inside **/users**, named **/add**. When user is redirected to **users/add** it loads the add component inside the blank users component.

#### Routes.js

```
<Route path="users" component={UserManagement}>
   <IndexRoute component={UsersListPage} />
   <Route path="add" component={UserAddInfo} />
</Route>
```

#### UserManagement Component

```
<div className="user-management">
  {this.props.children}
</div>
```